# Incorrect parameter value in Python Console in QGIS

Tags: python, qgis-python-console

I have a problem with python console.In Figure 1,the only thing I do is to define the 'inputFile' as 'filepath+fname' and 'outputFile' as 'FileSavedPath+fnameSaved'. But apparently there's an error. But it works totally fine in Figure 2.

How do I fix this problem?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Use os.path.join to concatenate the paths instead of filepath+fname, you have no OS separator between the end of the path and the file name so it's looking for the input called */volumes/users/laura/desktop/burwoodCAD_50.shp* instead of (I assume) */volumes/users/laura/desktop/burwood/CAD_50.shp*. In future can you please paste text and not just an image; the image is pretty but reading text is preferable as it's easier to copy and paste.

Comment: Thank you so much Michael. Yes, there's a lack of OS separator when I paste the file path. Definitely will avoid the image in the future.

Comment: @MichaelStimson, can you please move your comment to the answer?

Comment: I would not normally @fatih_dur as this is a python problem and not a GIS topic but I think there's a lesson here as it seems to pop up quite a lot so an answer seems appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is pythonic and not really a GIS topic. In the line where you concatenate `filepath+fname` there is no path separator so the path reads `/volumes/users/laura/desktop/burwoodCAD_50.shp` instead of the expected `/volumes/users/laura/desktop/burwood/CAD_50.shp`.

To avoid this problem use `os.path.join(filepath,fname)`, in this case and in *every case where you are joining paths to subfolders and files*, to concatenate the path and the file name. [os.path.join](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) uses the path separator that is appropriate for your OS, therefore it works equally as well in Windows, Mac and Linux.